# how to setState update property of object instance in child list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object quiz, it has a list of questions, questions have properties.

I want to update a property called `question` in object `question` (i know poor naming convention), inside `questions` without creating a separate instance of the selected question.

This is what I have so far (but it doesn't like the square bracket of selecting the particular question being edited):

```
onChange={(e) => setQuiz({ ...quiz, questions[quiz.questions.indexOf(selectedQuestion)].question: e.target.value })}
```

error:
`Unexpected token, expected ","`
img of syntax:
[image]

edit:

Here is a live demo example: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-dan-bv54nz?file=/src/App.js

I provide here a full working example and separate answer below incase this repo dies.

Full working code:

```
 const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({
    title: "",
    number: 6,
    questions: [
      { question: "item1", number: 3 },
      { question: "item2", number: 3 }
    ]
  });

  const [selectedQuestion, setSelectedQuestion] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedQuestion(0);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("quiz", quiz);
    console.log("quiz question", quiz.questions[0]);
  }, [quiz]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("selectedQuestion", selectedQuestion);
  }, [selectedQuestion]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={quiz.questions[selectedQuestion].question}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setQuiz({
            ...quiz,
            questions: quiz.questions.map((child, index) =>
              index === selectedQuestion
                ? { ...child, question: e.target.value }
                : child
            )
          })
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `but it doesn't like the square bracket of selecting the particular question being edited` doesn't like how? please elaborate and explain/show the errors to fix

Comment: @limco sorry, i have updated the question

Comment: the way you are trying to select the question entry in the array to update is probably different from how the object is formatted (hence the syntax error). Probably because you are trying not to create 'a separate instance of the selected question' - but it's the more-prone-to-error way of doing it. The answer by @hackape is a good (more structured) way to go about it.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve]? It would be nice to see the `quiz` state declaration and the UI/input that is using the `onChange` handler so we can more easily determine what is updating, and how & where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following @hackape & @Drew Reese suggestions I came up with the following:

The only real difference being also passing an index into the questions map so that it can correctly select the right element

```
onChange={(e) =>
          setQuiz({
            ...quiz,
            questions: quiz.questions.map((child, index) =>
              index === selectedQuestion
                ? { ...child, question: e.target.value }
                : child
            )
          })
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Super compact one-liner:

```js
onChange={e => setQuiz({ ...quiz, questions: quiz.questions.map(q => q === selectedQuestion ? { ...q, question: e.target.value } : q) })}
```

This piece of code is really way too compact and hard to read.

So I personally would extract it to a named function instead of inline it. One more thing, I always prefer the `setState(prevState => newState)` updater pattern instead of `setState(newState)` directly. It avoids stale closure problem.

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setQuiz((quiz) => {
      const questions = quiz.questions.map((q) => {
        if (q !== selectedQuestion) return q;
        return { ...q, question: e.target.value };
      });
      return { ...quiz, questions };
    })
  };

  /* ... */
  return <input onChange={handleChange} />
}
```

Comment: `(q) => q === selectedQuestion ? e.target.value : q` should be `(q) => q === selectedQuestion ? { ...q, question: e.target.value } : q`

Comment: I get errors trying this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'question')`

 @sanka sanjeewa doesnt give errors but updates all properties

Comment: @ABpositive You need to show me the code where this error happens. The code in my answer doesn't even read `'question'` property anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check whether this one work or not? (I just tried to prevent from above errors)

```
onChange={(e) => {
  const newQuestions = quiz.questions;
  newQuestions[quiz.questions.indexOf(selectedQuestion)].question = e.target.value;
  setQuiz({ ...quiz, questions: newQuestions });
}}
```

Comment: `newQuestions` is a reference into the existing state and this implementation mutates it. `Array.prototype.indexOf` also returns `-1` if no match is found, thus attempts 
 to mutate an undefined object at index `-1`.

Comment: @DrewReese Is it good to clone it? eg:- `const newQuestions =  Object.assign({}, quiz.questions)`

Comment: Not really, no. When updating React state you should shallow copy all state, and nested state, that is being updated. After "cloning" `quiz.questions` you'd still need to "clone" `newQuestions[<some index>]` into a new object reference.

Comment: @DrewReese I dont fully understand what you are saying, could you provide an example to contextualize?

Comment: @ABpositive Basically hackape's solution. See how `{ ...quiz }` shallow copies the previous state into a ***new*** object reference, then `quiz.questions.map(....)` shallow copies the `questions` array into a ***new*** array reference, *and then* `{ ...q, question: e.target.value }` shallow copies the specific question object into a ***new*** object reference. Each part of state that is being updated is a ***new*** reference.